# Instantiating a few hundred objects lags

Tags: java, performance

I'm new to Java.

I'm using BlueJ to try to create a text based game. I created a few hundred objects over a few days (every item I intend to have in the game) and they each have 10 ints, 1 double, and 3 strings. When I try to scroll or type in the editor it lags, badly. Is this just BlueJ or am I going about creating my items the wrong way?

In case that was hard to read: hundreds of objects, using BlueJ, editor lags. I made the items by instantiating all the objects at the start of the thread; should I do it a different way?

Comment: If the memory is full, it will throw an `OutOfMemoryError`. If all the hard work happens at the start of the thread, the source of the lag will be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Is it the IDE or your game lagging?

Answer (score -1):

I found out how to fix it: force restarting the computer. I don't know why it happened or why that fixed it though; if anyone would like to let me know so I can avoid it in the future that'd be great. :)

Comment: 1)  Not a good solution.  You most likely didn't need to restart your computer.  2) Not a good answer since ... a) we still really don't know what the question was: see the comments above, and b) it probably won't stop the problem recurring.

Comment: To answer the questions: no, I didn't get any errors, BlueJ just got slower and slower until it froze and I had to restart the computer. I know that it's not a good solution, but it's the only one I have. If someone else would like to correct it I would be very grateful.